# What to do when grub rescue does not recognize any of the partitions?

Tags: grubrescue

I had Win 7, Ubuntu (old), Kali 2017.

I wanted to erase Ubuntu so I deleted a partition using Win7, but I wasn't sure if it was Ubuntu's partition or not. When I restarted my computer the `grub rescue>` prompt came up. Now I can't do anything.

I tried checking the partitions using the `ls` command, but I couldn't find anything useful. I urgently need to get my system running again. What should I do?

Comment: refer to @karel 's comment.  no doubt grub (stage 1.5) was on ubuntu partition you've deleted - hence [grub] stage 1 points to somewhere invalid causing abend|jump to limited grub-rescue.   you can fix using windoze, or kali or a live media (eg. ubuntu-install cd/stick) as per instructions I saw as provided by Karel.